# SignalR попытка присоединиться к серверу

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

На сервере создаю Хаб

```
public class SGHub : Hub
{
    public static List<string> Users = new List<string>();

    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
        Console.WriteLine(SGHub.Users.Count);
    }
}
```

На клиенте подключаюсь к Хабу

```
void Start()
{
    hubConnection = new HubConnection(serverURL);
    hubConnection.Error += HubConnectionError;
    iHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateProxy("SGHub");
    Subscription subscription = iHubProxy.Subscribe("broadcastMessage");
    hubConnection.Start();
}
```

Если сервер не запущен, а клиент пытается приконектиться к Хабу приложение виснет, как этого избежать?

Comment: На чем виснет, на `hubConnection.Start()`? Или м.б. есть какая-нибудь ошикбка?

Comment: В этом случае hubConnection.Error молчит, ничего не выдаёт. 
Именно на `hubConnection.Start()`, после этой строки секунд 10 ничего не происходит, а потом приложение не отвечает.

Comment: @zRirez Ну все правильно, клиенты пытаются подключиться к несуществующему серверу, что бы избежать зависания, нужно сделать проверку, если сервер не создан вывести сообщение. К примеру, `if (hubConnection != null) или например if (serverURL != null)` а если ты по итогу получаешь какую либо ошибку тогда оберни свои данные в методе в `try {...} catch (...) {...}`

Comment: Просто фишка в том, что `hubConnection` и `serverURL` заданы правильно и не равны `null` и никаких исключений после начала выполнения функция `hubConnection.Start()` не выдаёт, клиент просто уходит "в себя" и ни на что не реагирует.